# How to implement LIKE(filter) on a list column using Sharepoint Rest API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, sharepoint

> How to implement LIKE on a column data of SharePoint list using REST API? 
>   Is there a way to achieve it?

**Current Situation:**

The API is working fine but the desired result is not to have the exact match.

**Required:**

All the names matching 'John' should come in response.

```
var URL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('UserList')/Items?$select=UserName&$filter=UserName eq 'John')";
var response = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: URL, async: false, dataType: "json"}).responseText;
var x = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(x);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to log the response to your console and inspect the logged array,
now try to use this filter

```
var URL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('UserList')/Items?$select=UserName&$filter=substringof('John',UserList);
```

Answer (score 0):

For text filed

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('TestList')/Items?$select=Title&$filter=substringof('John',textField)
```

For User field

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('TestList')/Items?$select=Title,UserName/Title&$expand=UserName&$filter=substringof('John',UserName/Title)
```